# Seekp function not being recognized in Xcode, C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to use the seekp function in order to return to the beginning of my binary file when reading.  However, the Xcode compiler doesn't seem to recognize the seek function.  The error given by the compiler is:

/Users/**/Desktop/Programming/Project/Project/Project.cpp:191:10: No member named 'seekp' in 'std::__1::basic_ifstream >'

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){


    ifstream f_in;
    f_in.open("Pixmap.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);

    ofstream f_out;
    f_out.open("Pos.txt", ios::binary);

    Handle_File_Errors(f_in, f_out);
    Pixel_Counter(f_in);
    f_in.seekp(0, ios::beg);


    f_in.close();
    f_out.close();

}
```

the Pixel_Counter function is written as follows:

```
void Pixel_Counter (ifstream &f_in) {

 uint null;
 int i=0;

 for (i=0; !f_in.eof();i++) {

 f_in.read((char*)&null, sizeof(null));

 }

 cout<<i-6<<endl;
 }
```

Finally, the Handle_File_Errors does not do anything with the read function but simply checks if the ifstream and ofstream functioned correctly.

Comment: "doesn't seem to" -- this is your interpretation, but you should provide observations instead, i.e. the precise error message. Also reduce your code to the smallest amount of code showing the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question including the error message given by Xcode.

Comment: Formally, your question is still off-topic because there's way too much code. Also, the error shows in line 191, which is way more lines than even the non-minimal code you provided has. The error could be anywhere in that hidden code, so please extract a minimal example.

Comment: [This site](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=seekp) is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

In an `ifstream` you should use [`seekg()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) instead of [`seekp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/), because you want to set the position for reading and not the position for writing.

[`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) and [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) have only the one of the two function.  An [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) can do both, but beware if it's for reading or writing.  [This tutorial](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/6542/fstream-tutorial) (especially the section about random access) could be of interest for you.

Comment: OK. It seems that it is recognised when using seekg.  Will it have the effect of bringing the pointer to the beginning of the binary file?

Comment: The usage is the same than seekp(). The only difference is that seekg() is for input and `seekp()' for output.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [`seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) for [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).
You probably meant either [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), or you wanted to use an [`ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) instead (which does have [`seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)).

Judging by your code, you seem to want input from the file, so [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) with your [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) is appropriate here.

Bear in mind that [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) are subtypes of [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) and [`ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) respectively.

---